# Storing file in CSV format in R looping

Tags: r

I have many data in same format in different directories and also I have one of function for processing those data.

I want to load all of my data and then process those data using my function and then store those data in CSV file.

When I use one of my data, code look like

```
ENFP_0719 <- f_preprocessing2("D:/DATA/output/ENFP_0719")
write.csv(ENFP_0719, "D:/DATA/output2/ENFP_0719.csv")
```

And everything is OK, file ENFP_0719.csv was created correctly.
But when I try to use looping, code looks like

```
setwd("D:/DATA/output")
file_list <- list.files()
for (file in file_list){
  file <- f_preprocessing2(print(eval(sprintf("D:/DATA/output/%s",file))))
  print("Storing data to csv....")
  setwd("D:/DATA/output2")
  write.csv(file, sprintf("%s.csv",file))
}
```

I got error like this

```
[1] "D:/DATA/output/ENFP_0719"
[1] "Storing data to csv...."
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  invalid 'description' argument
```

I've tried also to use paste `paste('data', file, 'csv', sep = '.')`
But I got same error. I am so confused with that error because nothing wrong with my function, I already show to you when I tried to use one data everything is ok.

So, whats wrong with my code, is it I have wrong in my loop code or in I have wrong when put parameters for `write.csv`.

I will wait for your light.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could make it a lot simpler by using the full.names argument to list.files and making a few other changes like this:

```
path = 'data/output'
file_list <- list.files('data/output', full.names=TRUE)
for (file in file_list) {
  file_proc <- f_preprocessing2(file)
  new_path <- gsub('output', 'output2', file)
  write.csv(file_proc, new_path)
}
```